# choose ML model for transportation

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree

0.Suppose, you have to work with an ML problem, where you have to predict
the number of oxygen tanks needed to be shipped from Indonesia. Which
of the following ML algorithm you will choose:
a. Logistic regression
b. Decision Tree
c. Both of the above
d. none of the above

choose an option for ml model

Comment: I have a strong feeling you have zero understanding of what is regression and prediction. If you did you would provide data and requirements (prediction of what, when, which circumstances etc), and then very likely you would not need to ask those questions.

Comment: sorry but this was a quiz question asked. there is no data provided. the only hint is that i a have to predict number of tanks, so this is a regression quiz. and you are right i am a newbie

Comment: Well, SO is about programming, not doing homework for others.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @SudiptoKumar Those services are doing elaborated copy paste, they do not understand and they do not explain anything. If you want to understand, you need to put yourself into the question and the concepts. BTW you can add e) bootstrap f) SVM g) Ho Kashyap h) HMM